# Please increase the question limit during beta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions, beta

I'm running into the question limit on ham.stackexchange.com, and I'm wondering what value the question limit adds during the beta.  It seems to me that the workload is light enough that bad questions will be caught, and keeping content fresh and activity high, even if it's from just a handful of users, would have a higher priority than preventing people, especially early adopters, from asking "too man questions".

Can we have the limits during beta re-evaluated and either removed or raised?

Comment: What are the current "limits"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, beta sites *don't* have the per-month and per-day limits enabled.

However, we will enable them if necessary to handle abuse (spam, trolling or simply waves of poorly-asked questions). And apparently this was done on Ham (I really should be able to remember why, but... I'm drawing a blank).

I've turned this off.

Comment: Can we see the shiny checkbox you use to turn it on and off?

Comment: It involves typing "False" into a textbox, @Undo.

Comment: "False". There, did I do it right?

Comment: The reason why was that a particular user essentially copy/pasted the entire list of questions from the definition phase, many of which were low quality.

Comment: Ahhh... that does ring a bell. Thanks, @PearsonArtPhoto